# What causes this for loop to print a series of nil?

Tags: clojure

Can anyone explain what causes all the nil values in the following?

```
(defn my-for []
   (for [n (range 0 40)]
     (println n)))
(my-for)
```

Result (omitting some numerical values):

(0
1
2
...
30
31
nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil 32
33
...
38
39
nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` is a list comprehension operator, its return value is a list. The return value of `println` is always `nil`, and those are the values that `for` is using to build the list it returns. Since you are `(println n)`, your prints interleave with the REPL's printing of the return value for the `for`.

If you avoid the use of `println` in the `for`, the REPL will show you the list of numbers from 0 to 39:

```
(defn my-for []
   (for [n (range 0 40)] n))
(my-for)
;= (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39)
```

If you only want to print the values then you can use the `doseq` form, which is used for side-effecting functions (such as `println`) and always returns `nil`:

```
(defn my-doseq []
   (doseq [n (range 0 40)] 
     (println n)))
(my-doseq)
```

Comment: Many thanks. Knowing that `println` returns `nil` surely explains why I experienced this as an odd behaviour. Great info on the doseq form.

Answer (score 5):

this is a mix of the output of the print statement and printing the result of the for expression.

the for produces a sequence of the return value of println, which is always `nil`

```
user> (defn my-for []                                                                                                                                                     
           (for [n (range 0 40)]                                                                                                                                          
                     (println n)))                                                                                                                                        
#'user/my-for                                                                                                                                                             
user> (def ansewr (doall (my-for)))                                                                                                                                       
0                                                                                                                                                                         
1                                                                                                                                                                         
2                                                                                                                                                                         
3                                                                                                                                                                         
...                                                                                                                                                                       
38                                                                                                                                                                        
39                                                                                                                                                                        
#'user/ansewr                                                                                                                                                             
user> ansewr                                                                                                                                                              
(nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)
```

These two are being printed ontop of each other by the repl

Comment: Ah that explains it. I was stumped to see the nil clumped together like that. Thanks.

Comment: @droidballoon the nils are clumped together like that because of the chunking behavior of `for` - lazy seqs are sometimes calculated in chunks of 32 at a time.